# How can I make players share damage using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map where I want players to share damage - when player 1 takes some amount of damage, player 2 will also get damaged that same amount. I used scoreboards with health, did a scoreboard to test for player's health and I know how to damage using potion effects, but I don't know how to testfor and deal damage to one specific player (the player with higher health).

Could I get some advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dummy variable and [target selector arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).

### Run once

Have a dummy score, call it `healthDif`.

```
/scoreboard objectives add healthDif dummy
```

### Run every tick, in order

Set each players `healthDif` score to their own health score:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] healthDif = @a[c=1] health
```

Subtract the other player's `healthDif` score from your own:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] healthDif -= @a[rm=0] health
```

Now players with a positive `healthDif` score will have more health than the other player. Target with @a[score_healthDif=1]
Note this will only work for two players. In order for it to work with more, you have to take a few extra steps.

---

### Run once

First you'll need a dummy variable to store miscellaneous variables. Call it `vars`. **Note: If you already have a variable for this (you likely do), you can skip this step.**

```
/scoreboard objectives add vars dummy
```

### Run every tick, in order

Put these between the two commands from before.

First, set the `#nplayers` to 0:

```
/scoreboard players set #nplayers vars -1
```

Now, have each player increment `#nplayers`:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add #nplayers vars 1
```

Finally, multiply each players `healthDif` score by this number

```
/scoreboard players operation @a healthDif *= #nplayers vars
```

This way, you can have any amount of players, and the system automatically adapts!

Comment: I'm still kind of unsure how to set this up for the two player one. Sorry I suck lol.

Comment: The one fit more players will work for two as well.  If using 1.9+, the run every tick should be done with command block chaining. Otherwise, use a fill clock.

Comment: Also, if this answer works for you, please use the "accept" button.